# How to configure the Blogger API in Google Developer?

Tags: service, blogger, google-developers-console

Developer Console of Google is not granting the access of Blogger.
After login into an developer console I tried to on the blogger API v3 it gives me the another form but after submitting that form it gives request accessing like in API services page.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button to enable the Blogger API it opens up a new form in which you have to submit data like the number of request quota you want etc etc. and then google guy will reply back with the URL and you need to wait for it.

once you get the URL you have to enable the API within 2 days.